# How to remotely configure Antminer S19 Pro+ hash rate or ideally power limit in Watts (wattage)

Tags: miner-configuration, hashpower, antminer, energy-consumption

I am helping a friend set up his Antminer S19 Pro+ miner and due to fluctuating power availability, he needs to control the hash rate, or ideally power usage (in wattage) remotely.

Is it possible to remotely control the hash rate or power limit on the S19 Pro+ using the stock firmware?

I looked around and could find no official documentation on how to do this. There exists commercial firmware that charge pool commission, which seem to tune power usage by controlling the hash rate in a feedback loop. However, this seems like a basic configuration setting that should be modifiable by an API, or low-level interface.

I am a professional programmer and can interface with any socket, websocket or API that the Antminer exposes, even if it means reverse-engineering their web interface.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: It seems you can configure the "miner-mode" on the stock firmware via the web UI's HTTP API, but I haven't tried it yet: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvoPg2Hu2hc&feature=youtu.be